# Angular Stepper Form Data with Array of steps

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6, angular-material-stepper

created a stepper steps with data values with below

Component Level

```
environment = [DEV,TEST,UAT,PROD]
```

HTML

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
<div *ngFor ="let env of environment ; let i =index")
<mat-step [StepControl]= 'diformGroup'>

<form #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="pipe">
<input matInput >
</form>
</mat-step>

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

as expected the steps as are coming as  DEV- TEST- UAT - PROD , but the issue is all the steps having same form data .i wanted to publish each step with separate form group data. can any one help how to achieve this

if add another step it increase the step level.

Comment: the [stepControl] -be carefullty, Angular is case -sensitive -you has put StepControl-) need a FormControl or FormGroup.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the stack blitz sample that you have provided and I suggest the following, even though there are also other ways of handling the controls such as having form control arrays for dynamic data, but as I don't know what is your scenario stick to the assumption that you have 4 steps and you want to have their values stored in a form control.

- Make a `FormGroup` with keys you are trying to loop (this can be done also dynamically based on your preferences)

```html
 formGroupObj = new FormGroup({
    DEV: new FormControl(),
    TEST: new FormControl(),
    UAT: new FormControl(),
    PROD: new FormControl()
  });
```

- In your `component.html` file now you can map the steppers to their own `FormControl` object as follows

```html
<button mat-raised-button (click)="isLinear = !isLinear" id="toggle-linear">
  {{!isLinear ? 'Enable linear mode' : 'Disable linear mode'}}
</button>

<mat-horizontal-stepper lablePosition="bottom" [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <mat-step *ngFor="let env of environment" [formGroup]="formGroupObj">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>{{env.label}}</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Answer</mat-label>
        <input matInput [formControlName]="env.label">
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext (click)="printControl()">Next</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

- And the following is just a piece of code giving you the idea of how to access these control values. If you exactly implement what you see here you will see the progress of the form group filling up with the corresponding data as you click "next".

```html
  printControl() {
    this.environment.forEach(item=>{
      let formVal = this.formGroupObj.controls[item.label].value;
      console.log('value for control ' + item.label + ' is: '+ formVal);
    });
  }
```

Comment: this works when you have steps declared as static and then you can carve your data as form inside each step. But my situation is when i assigned steps which are from the data  array ,which means an variable is having step details as said environment =['DEV','TEST','UAT','PROD'], all the formgroup data for each step  should come as unique formdata associated with step  not  same , as unique.let me see if I can push stackbliz

Comment: html code <mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" *ngFor="let env of environmnet">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>{{env}}</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>   ts code just add  environmnet =["DEV","TEST","UAT","PROD"]

Comment: can any one help with this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-stepper212